# Вопрос про IOPS на HDD

Tags: файловая-система, hdd

С одной стороны утверждается, что последовательный доступ к HDD обеспечивает пропускную способность со скоростью 100Мб/сек.

С другой стороны известно, что диски ограничены числом элементарных операций ввода-вывода в секунду - IOPS.
Для HDD ограничение по IOPS - около 200.

Во всяких мануалах по дискам пишут, что под IOPS обычно понимается запись или чтение блока данных размером 4Кб.

Что ж, умножим 200 * 4Кб = 800Кб.

Как эта цифра в 800Кб соотносится со скоростью в 100Мб/сек в случае последовательного доступа?

Comment: Вы не совсем верно поняли термин IOPS, это не количество считываемых "блоков" с диска, а количество операций, ака - позиционирование головки и начало считывания блока данных, а вот считываемый блок за операцию - может достигать десятков мегабайт.

Comment: кмк в том то и дело iops == отдельные операции i\o (начатые и полностью завершенные - передача кучи мелких файлов не просто так считается простейшим iops бенчмарком). конец файла - конец операции i/o и требует засэйвить транзакцию в фс таблице(запись на другой конец блина), в то время как запись\чтение любого кол-ва >4кб непрерывных данных все еще одна операция. кмк последовательным доступом как раз это и называется. впрочем "я не настоящий сварщик". upd: пока писал уже ответили :3

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков правильно ли я понимаю, что говорить об IOPS в случае последовательного доступа особо нет смысла? т.е. будто бы получается, что диск прочитает 100Мб файл, лежащий на диске в блоках, выделенных один за другим,  за один-два IOPS?  
И говорить об IOPS имеет смысл в контексте случайного доступа?

Comment: Нет не совсем, размер блока ограничен, но ограничение это не столь мало(4кб), сколько он точно - сказать не могу, не вдавался в такие подробности, подозреваю что это как то связано с размером сектора \ дорожки, но утверждать не возьмусь. в любом случае после чтения дорожки даже при последовательном доступе - нужно менять позицию головки на соседнюю 
 дорожку :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо, стало вроде понятно. могли бы оформить комментарии как ответ на вопрос, отмечу его галочкой :)